# Minimization Procedure Decreases Quickly & then Increases

Tags: matlab, optimization, numerical-methods

I running the "interior-point" algorithm of MATLAB's FMINCON. The algorithm uses BFGS and thus takes into account information in the numerical Hessian.

I am optimizing over a parameter space that is known to be non-convex with respect to a unique solution. I penalize those parameter-combinations that are not unique with an arctan function.

I'm finding the optimization procedure starts high (around 10), in a few iteration decreases 'til 4 (near the minimum), and then increases slowly back towards 10 over a few hundred iteration.

I have options set to rescale the problem and constraints.

I'm kind of stuck at this point. What do you think?

Comment: Have you tried changing your initial guess for the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

My particular problem I found was caused by `fmincon`'s `scale` option which I had to set `scale-Obj-Cons`. I believe this was messing up the numerical gradient and hessian calculation as the determinant region is non-convex.